# laravel orderby nested related model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have model with name `"Date"` which has relationship `(one-to-one)` with `"Tour"` and `"Tour"` Model has relationship  `(many-to-many)` with `"Type"` Model.
I want to order my Date Records Based on `"Type"` name. Unfortunately I don't have any clue to do it with eloquent.

`Date model:`

```
public function Tour()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Tour');
}
```

`Tour model:`

```
public function Date()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('\App\Date','tour_id');
    }
 public function Types()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Type');
    }
```

`Type model:`

```
public function Tours()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Tour');
    }
```

and my `controller` for output:

```
public function tourList()
    {

        $dates = new Date();
        $dates = $dates->orderBy('id','asc')
            ->paginate(6)
            ->appends([
            'sort_price' => request('sort_price'),
            'minmax' => request('minmax'),
            'type' => request('type')
        ]);
        return view('primary.Tour.list', compact(['dates']));
}
```

Comment: do u need tours records? or date records? at final.

Comment: You can't do date record order based on type record using relationship builder. You have to use join here.

Comment: For eloquent join I can help for you.

Comment: How do you want to order `Date` if it has multiple `Type`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateRes = Date::join('type_tour as TT', 'TT.tour_id', '=', 'date.tour_id')
         ->join('type as T','TT.type_id','=','T.id')
         ->orderBy('T.name')
         ->get();
```

See if it is work for you.

Comment: not working,i think your code is wrong , because relationship between tour and type is many-to-many and there is not "tour_id" column exist in types table.

Comment: What ref column you have in type table?

Comment: between tour and type is another table with name type_tour which has two column tour_id and type_id. and if you mean of ref column is, which column i want to orderBy it, its "name" column inside type table. i thinks second line of your code have problem.

Comment: And where do you store data_id ref in tour table?

Comment: store tour_id inside Date table. i don't have any date_id column.

Comment: not working. Error : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'date.tour_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select * from `dates` inner join `tour_type` as `TT` on `TT`.`tour_id` = `date`.`tour_id` inner join `types` as `T` on `TT`.`type_id` = `T`.`id` order by `T`.`name` asc)

Comment: I just assumed the Date table name  is 'date'. I dont have idea what table name you have for date in database. Please replace date by your date table name.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to order the result based on nested relation column, you must use a chain of joins:

```
$result= Date::join('tours','tours.id','=','dates.tour_id')
->leftJoin('type_tour','type_tour.tour_id','=','tours.id')
->leftJoin('types','types.id','type_tour.type_id')
->orderBy('types.name')->get();
```

make sure the relation middle table between tours & types table is type_tour
it might be tour_type or something else ...

please note that if you want to order by multiple columns you could add 'orderBy' clause as much as you want:

```
->orderBy('Types.id', 'DESC')->orderby('Types.name', 'ASC') //... ext
```

check my answer here:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/61194625/10573560